# Wierd form offset look/bug?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, offset

I'm not sure whats going on here it's all offset :/

http://jsfiddle.net/aaL9gemz/2/

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A screenshot is not enough here. Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that presents the problem. We're missing CSS.

Comment: Didn't close the .row correctly. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

[BootPly Example](http://www.bootply.com/0nhA7vfKL6)

```
<div class="container-fluid"> <!-- OR <div class="container"> -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure what's causing that weird layout, but putting this form inside a container seems to alleviate this issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that It's kinda fixed it but not quite now it takes up the whole screen

Comment: Yeah `container-fluid` is fullscreen. Use `container` to make it smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the first `.row` in the correct location. It's best to comment code so you know where you are.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft">
   </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="In Game Name">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How long have you been playing Minecraft">
   </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

This goes inside a `.container` or `.container-fluid`.